# ffmpeg key frames not being respected

Tags: ffmpeg, video-conversion

I'm trying to splice a variety of videos at the exact same timestamps. My working command forces key frames at each of those timestamps and then uses `segment_frames` to do the job. The problem is, it doesn't work for every video and I'm not sure why.

`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:v libx264 -force_key_frames  timestampsArray -preset ultrafast -f segment -segment_frames keyframesArray -reset_timestamps 1 -map 0:0 output%03d.mp4`

Some of the outputs are perfect while others are out of whack. I probed a few good and a few bad input videos to see if there was a pattern in the settings, but there doesn't seem to be.

For a visual demonstration, here are 4 outputs. The bottom two tracks are accurate and have a correct split at the 2 second mark, but the top two diverge.

[Image of the good and bad outputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d7QrB.png)

Let me know what else I can provide to help you help me. Fwiw, I don't need audio. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

After a bit more digging I realize now that ffmpeg actually output what was expected for all cases. The issue was actually introduced when I dropped the clips into Premiere. When the framerate of the sequence did not align with the framerate of the clip, it became unsynced. This is new territory for me so I'm not sure yet if my solution is optimal.

By introducing `-r 24` right before my output file in the command, I was able to align the timestamps rendered in Premiere and solve the problem I described. My assumption is that so long as I'm always reducing the framerate from the input to the output, 24 frames per second should appear crisp. Let me know if that's untrue. Thanks.